# Icon in WPF Browser application

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010, xaml, clickonce

I have a WPF Browser Application consisting mostly of wpf pages which I'm developing in Visual Studio 2010. 
I'm publishing the app to the intranet, with ClickOnce at full trust.

Is there any way to have an icon for the pages in this type of application? (which would show instead of the internet explorer icon in each of the tabs of Internet Explorer), I'm executing it through PresentationHost.exe.

What I'm trying to do, is to have a desktop shortcut with a custom icon for each part of the application (two different projects in the same solution).

If there isn't a way to do it with XAML, is there any way to run any commands or a batch file at the moment of accepting the ClickOnce prompt?, to place the shortcuts in the desktop with their respective icons at the moment of installing the application.

Thanks in advance, Jesús.

P.S: I know my redaction skills suck, so if any more details are needed, let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you open your project file and change the HostInBrowser setting to false, and this will enable the ability to provide an Icon and Manifest in the project's properties.

```
<HostInBrowser>False</HostInBrowser>
```

I am not sure how that will affect your app though. Maybe this setting is supposed to be "True" to work how you need it to work.

Comment: this solution worked for me, however, after publishing, i'm not able to debug with this setting on False. But at least it's easy to change.. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Did you set the icon for each project, in VS right click on the project - properties - Icon and manifest - click the icon button ...

Comment: That option is greyed out (on the Application tab of the properties), i think it's because it's a WPF Browser Application, but i haven't found much info on the matter.